# how to apply a change event on mutiple elements, that are stored as variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I mean I know something like :

```
$(".class1, #idAbc, div.blahblah .etc").change(function( ...
```

is ok

But what if I already have :

```
myVar1 = $(".class1");
myVar2 = $("#idAbc");
myVar3 = $("div.blahblah .etc");
```

and I also have to apply the same event function on them ?

Do I need to write an event for each of them ?

I think I'd rather put the variabkles in an array and then iterate to apply the event, but what's the simplest way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myVar1.add(myVar2).add(myVar3).on('change', ...)
```

http://api.jquery.com/add/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.selector` property of jQuery object

```
$(`${myVar1.selector},${myVar2.selector},${myVar3.selector}`)
.on("change", function() {})
```

Comment: thank you I didn't know that kind of reflective thing